# How to convert UV position to local position and vice-versa?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position

I'm working in a project that has a layer system represented by several planes in front of each other. These planes receive different textures, which are projected in a render texture with an orthographic camera to generate composite textures.

This project is being build on top of another system (a game), so I have some restrictions and requirements in order to make my project work as expected to fit properly in this game. One of the requirements refers to the decals, which has their position and scale represented by a single Vector4 coordinate. I believe that this Vector4, represents 4 vertex positions in both X and Y axis (2 for X and 2 for Y). For a better understanding, see the image below:

[image]

It happens that these Vector4 coordinates seems to be related with the UV of the texture where they belong, cause they only have positive values between 0 and 1. I'm facing a hard time trying to fit this coordinate together with my project, cause Unity position system uses the traditional cartesian plane with positive and negative values rather than the normalized UV coordinates. So if I use the original Vector4 coordinates of the game, the decals get wrongly positioned and vice versa (I'm using the original coordinates as base, but my system is meant to generate stuff to be used within the game, so these decal's coordinates must match the game standards).

Considering all this, how could I convert the local/global position used by Unity as UV position used the game?

Anyway, I tried my best to explain my doubt, not sure if it has an easy solution or not. I figured out this Vector4 stuff only from observation, so feel free to suggest other ideas if you think I'm wrong about it.

EDIT #1 - Despite some paragraphs, I'm afraid my intensions can be more clear, so complementing, the whole point is to find a way to position the decals using the Vector4 coordinates in a way that they get in the right positions. The layer system contains bigger planes, which has the full size of the texture plus smaller ones, representing the decals, varying in size. I believe that the easiest solution would be use one of these bigger planes as the "UV area", which would have the normalized positions mentioned. But I don't know how would I do that...